# Why are my messages hidden under the keyboard in the Hangouts app?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note-2, google-hangouts

Whenever I respond to an SMS or a gTalk/Hangouts message, it is hidden under the keyboard. Afterwards, if whomever I am talking with responds, their message is hidden further below. This is causing me to constantly scroll the conversation up to see what's the latest message is.

When looking in a thread, and pulling a keyboard to type something, everything looks fine. This only happens after initiating a conversation by sending a message.

My device is a Verizon Galaxy Note II running CyanogenMod 11.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Galaxy Note 3.

Comment: So is it a Samsung issue... Note issue? What or version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is also an animation issue. According to an [answer for my dialer app](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/61786/50481), setting the animation to .5x fixes a lot of spacing/hiding issues on the phone.

To fix it, do the following:

> Go to `Settings > Developer Options`
>
> Change `Animator Duration Scale` to `0.5x`

Many props to [Abid Rahman K](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/23162/abid-rahman-k) for figuring it out!